# Automatically sending SMS message

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I write a sms sending application. Details are given below:

I have a button, when I click the button, sms should automatically be sent to the recipient without opening the message writing area. I should just get a pop message saying "sms sent".

Sms content is a default content. 
Please help me with full code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Apple does not provide that functionality, thankfully: malicious apps could use that to send SMS to premium services.

Comment: Or just generally spam your friends. +1.

Comment: @user2632844 The reply to the question “can we do this” is the first sentence of the answer you are commenting on: “You can't.”

Comment: @user2632844 No, you cannot. Only by integrating a commercial SMS service like Twilio, which will charge _you_ for sending the SMS.

Comment: @user2632844 What part of "no" don't you understand? **This is not possible, due to potential abuses.**